# Passing Callback to chrome.storage.sync.get

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get extension preferences in content script by asking from background.js.

**contentscript.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'action' : 'preferences'}, 
    function(prefs) {
        console.log(prefs);
    }
);
```

**background.js**

```
function onRequest(request, sender, callbackOfContentScript) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(items){
        callbackOfContentScript(items);
    });
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onRequest);
```

`console.log` in content script returns `undefined`.

What is the issue here?

Comment: What is `onRequest`? Do you use [`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#simple) ?

Comment: yes exactly forget to add that. I am adding now.

Comment: It would be easier to store your preferences in `storage.local`. `storage.local` is directly available to your content script, in addition to scripts in the background context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an async message passing. The [onMessage docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessage) says that you have to `return true` in a `sendResponse` callback if you are going to make it async.

> ...unless you **return true** from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called).

So, the solution will be:

**background.js**

```js
function onRequest(request, sender, callbackOfContentScript) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(items){
        callbackOfContentScript(items);
    });
    return true; // <-- it makes the job
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onRequest);
```